# C++ using-declaration for non-type function templates of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Having read several answers on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929869/c-calling-template-functions-of-base-class)), I figured out the two usual alternatives for calling a function template in a template base:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    template<int N>
    auto get() const
    {
        return N;   
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
    //first alternative
    auto f0() const { return this-> template get<0>(); }   

    //second alternative
    auto f1() const { return Base<T>::template get<1>(); }    
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d8e8c1fa85d49ff)

But is there also an equivalent to the `using Base<T>::foo` declaration for non-template functions? Maybe something like

```
template<int N>
using Base<T>::template get<N>;  //does not compile in gcc
```

Comment: See [CWG 109](http://wg21.link/cwg109)

Comment: @T.C. So it's not part of the standard and my partial(!) answer only shows the extension provided by VS2015?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `using` you might redeclare the function with something like:

```
template<int N> auto get() const{ return Base<T>::template get<N>(); }
```

---

This code works with VS2015, but not with coliru:

```
using Base<T>::template get;
template<int N>
auto f3() { return get<N>(); }
```

From my understanding after reading the [commenty by T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197659/c-using-declaration-for-non-type-function-templates-of-template-base-class/35198932#comment-58114164) this is a custom extension of VS2015 and the behaviour is not part of the standard and might even be considered as *ill-formed*.

---

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get it to work with your `using` either. However, if the intent is to simplify the cumbersome invocation syntax, then you might find the following alternative useful. I think it gives a similar effect.

```
template<typename T> 
struct Base 
{ 
    template<int N> 
    auto get() const 
    { 
        return N;    
    } 
}; 

template<typename T> 
struct Derived : public Base<T> 
{ 
    auto f0() const  
    {  
        auto get_0 = Base<T>::template get<0>; 

        get_0(); 
    }    

    //second alternative 
    auto f1() const  
    {  
        auto get_1 = Base<T>::template get<1>; 

        get_1(); 
    }     
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is clear. One can also define `template<int N> auto get() const {return this-> template get<N>(); }` at class scope (and possibly the equivalent for a non-const version of get). The question was explicitly about the templated using declaration.